# "tuple" object has no attribute "read"

Tags: python, tkinter

My tkinker Python script is not working, it says the error ""tuple" object has no attribute "read"", how could I fix this?

My code is here: https://pastebin.com/kLnmutcg

My theory why it says this error is in this code:

```py
def save():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("txt files","*.txt"),("All files","*.*")))
    file = open=(filename, "wt")

def open():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("txt files","*.txt"),("All files","*.*")))
    file = open=(filename, "rt")
    read = file.read()
    text_box.insert(tk.END, read)
```

I'm trying to make a notepad clone of sorts.

Comment: If you get this error it is often because your variable has been defined incorrectly or was inadvertently redefined, so that is always worth checking.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
file = open(filename, "wt")
```

By using `file = open=(filename, "wt")` you create two variables: `file` and `open`, that both contain a tuple `(filename, "wt")`

Also do not use `open` as variable/function name, this is a python builtin. You can find a [list of python builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Now this spits out an error called "open() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given"

Comment: Make sure to restart your interpreter. If you messed with variable names you might have overwritten `open` with something else

Comment: Huh, I am using VS and restarted it multiple times during this

Comment: @Mikus You defined a function called `open()`. Don't define things with the same name as builtins. Call your function something else, like `open_file()`